# How do I integrate events created on eventbrite.com to automatically update to my personal website?

Tags: javascript, integrate, eventbrite

I want to create events on eventbrite.com and have my website automatically update it's upcoming events list with any event I've created on eventbrite without having to go in and add in the events or widget pages into my website. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/
For a list of all of the different commands you can use to interface with eventbrite along with the documentation on how to do it. It's a much bigger task than what you'd want to get yourself into.